# Reordering eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to shuffle the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix from a dynamic system because I want to know the evolution of each eigenvalue with time.

I have searched online and the Matlab package [eigenshuffle](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22885-eigenshuffle), which I implemented in Python, seems to give the best result so far.  However, it fails at picking up the right mode after some cross-overs, as illustrated below with the dash line.

[image]

The algorithm creates a distance function between the eigenmodes and uses [Munkres algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to find the minimum distances between eigenmodes. The only difference between Matlab's [eigenshuffle](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22885-eigenshuffle) and the Python code I implemented was that Matlab [eigenshuffle](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22885-eigenshuffle) sort the eigenvalues before shuffling based on the real part while I think it makes sense in my application to sort based on the absolute values.

Does anyone have a better approach on reorder the eigenvalues?

Comment: The problem that you are dealing with is known as the "eigenvalue reordering problem". You will find functions for this problem in, say, LAPACK, ScaLAPACK, and the new task-based StarNEig library. There are numerical issues related to swapping pairs of eigenvalues that you need to consider if you do it yourself.

Comment: I want to know the evolution of the eigenvalues with time.

Comment: @CarlChristian Could you give examples of some of those functions in LAPACK or ScaLAPACK.? Between, my eigenvalues are complex numbers, I think some reorodering algorithm are not fir for complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @David Eigenvalues changing over time?  What matrix-valued function do you have?

Comment: @Rodrigo The input matrix is the Jacobian of the solution of an ODE solver at each time step.

Comment: Please include the ODE and details in the question itself.

Comment: It's a combustion modeling problem, I don't think it will be necessary here. Everything else works fine. I just want to shuffle the eigenvalues so I can easily plot the continuous evolution of the eigenvalues with time.

Comment: Why? ODEs from physics tend to be "well-behaved".  Such details matter.  And why do you want to plot the eigenvalues over time?

Comment: You can mention what kind of ODE it is.  Knowing whether it is Lipschitz or not matters.